# SharePoint 2013: adding disable-output-escaping to a list

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I can see that disable-output-escaping is a tag you can add to a page's XSL to properly render HTML entered as a value in a list item. What I can't figure out is HOW to add that tag. I've found a lot of documentation for SharePoint 2010, but can't figure out how to do it in 2013 with SharePoint Designer.

The reason why I'm trying to use this is so that I can use a calculated field to display a picture based on the value of a yes/no field in the same list.

This is the list:
[link removed, site no longer available]

As seen in the list, my calculated field works correctly to output HTML based on the yes/no value of the "Cats" column, but it's escaping the text instead of rendering it.

Caveat: this is my first time doing anything outside of what InfoPath and the SharePoint web interface can do, so if I'm doing this completely wrong, I'm open to recommendations on best practices in this scenario.

Comment: I assume you have access to the XSLT files? If so could you include a minimal example into your question and point out where portion of your XSLT you would like to output with the disabled output escaping?

Comment: That's part of what I can't figure out - where the XSLT is. This is a list using the default XSLT. I haven't customized anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for xslt. You can (unsupported) trick SharePoint to output a Calculated Column as HTML by setting the datatype to Number

Comment: That works! Thank you! I was hoping to use emoji, but I think that's a little too advanced...I should be able to use CSS to accomplish what I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable output escaping on a "per column" basis in the pages sourcecode.

**Standard output**

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Editor" /></td><td class="ms-vb">
```

**Escaped output**

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Editor" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></td><td class="ms-vb">
```